# How can I add a unique count of a specific field to my report?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, report-viewer2010

I have a C# program with output that looks like this (unexpanded rows):
[image: unexpanded rows]

and this (expanded rows):
[image: expanded rows]

Here's my SQL for the Fill method:

```
SELECT       MBRSEP, LOCATION, BILLMOYR, RATE
FROM         CAR1.CAV_MBRHISTDETL
WHERE        (BILLMOYR IN ('1104', '1105', '1106', '1107', '1108', '1109')) AND (RATE = '0096')
ORDER BY     BILLMOYR ASC, MBRSEP ASC
```

What this report is showing is a breakdown of customers with a rate type of 0096 for the months of April, May, June, July, August, and September.

What I'd like to see is a unique count for each distinct customer (MBRSEP) (a grand total of unique customers for those months), but I can't get my head around how to do this.  Can anyone help or point me in the right direction?  This little program was written with Visual Studio 2010 using a blank form, a databound dataset, and a reportviewer control.

EDIT: Also, here is the report source on the report design screen:

[image: report source]

On the designer screen, I'm assuming there's some way to add a field that will show total number of unique values in a certain field in the report, but I'm not sure how to do that. (NOTE: I just added the SQL statements in a text field on the report for clarity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the SSRS [CountDistinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155923%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) function?

Comment: That did it.  I added a field to the report and typed: [CountDistinct(MBRSEP)] and it worked like a charm.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

If I read this correctly, you want to find how many customers you had:

```
SELECT       count(distinct MBRSEP) TotalCustomers
FROM         CAR1.CAV_MBRHISTDETL
WHERE        (BILLMOYR IN ('1104', '1105', '1106', '1107', '1108', '1109')) AND (RATE = '0096')
ORDER BY     BILLMOYR ASC, MBRSEP ASC
```

Comment: That is correct.  I'd like to get the 'count' of distinct MBRSEP.  I can do this in the query, as you posted above, but how can I add it to my report?  Will the field "TotalCustomers" be available to me in the report design screen?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with report viewer.